# Titanium appcelerator failing on build

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am trying to run my app in the iPad simulator, but I keep getting this error whenever I try to simulate. I've updated everything, some fellow help for an appcelerator noob would be much appreciated. Any thoughts would help.

```
[ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] :   Ld "build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Neoplastic Heme.app/Neoplastic Heme" normal i386
[ERROR] :  (1 failure)
```

This is what I am getting in xcode for my first error. Maybe this helps.

```
Ld "/Users/john/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Neoplastic_Heme-amibyrwaylsahtgseinqplkoqzqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Neoplastic Heme.app/Neoplastic Heme" normal i386
cd "/Users/john/Desktop/Neoplastic Heme/build/iphone"
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.0
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk -L/Users/john/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Neoplastic_Heme-amibyrwaylsahtgseinqplkoqzqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator "-L/Users/john/Desktop/Neoplastic Heme/build/iphone/lib" -F/Users/john/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Neoplastic_Heme-amibyrwaylsahtgseinqplkoqzqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist "/Users/john/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Neoplastic_Heme-amibyrwaylsahtgseinqplkoqzqx/Build/Intermediates/Neoplastic Heme.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Neoplastic Heme-iPad.build/Objects-normal/i386/Neoplastic Heme.LinkFileList" -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -weak_framework iAd -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=4.0 -framework Foundation -weak_framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreLocation -framework MapKit -framework MessageUI -framework MobileCoreServices -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AudioToolbox -weak_framework MediaPlayer -framework AVFoundation -lxml2 -framework StoreKit -lTiCore -ltiverify -lti_ios_debugger -licucore -o "/Users/john/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Neoplastic_Heme-amibyrwaylsahtgseinqplkoqzqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Neoplastic Heme.app/Neoplastic Heme"
```

Comment: Some code or at the very least some information would be good..

Comment: It is not my code, I am basically trying to untangle this first problem from another developer.. What other information would you need?

Comment: Did you take over this previous developers computer or just the code?  Are you just building the code in xcode or are you using the Titanium code?

Comment: I am taking just the code over, different computer. I am using the Titanium code.

Comment: The second part is from xcode. I thought it would maybe help something in the troubleshooting process.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Clean the build. Many errors can be fixed by performing a clean build. http://www.titaniumtips.com/files/how_to_clean_the_build_folder.php

Comment: Thank you soooooo much!!! :)

I went to your link and emptied out my iPhone folder like it said to. I then went to build it and it worked out perfectly. Made my day!

Comment: You're welcome :-) Took me many months of using Titanium to figure this out. Like I said, if you come into problems again and you don't know why clean your build.

Answer (score 7):

I recently encountered this error too. In my case the solution was to update/remove any modules build for older SDK versions.

My modules hadn't been updated in a while but the Titanium SDK has. The error wasn't very informative but once I removed the module the error disappeared and I could build again.

But before trying this, always try to clean the project. It usually helps! That should be the first step, if that doesn't work, try my solution.

Comment: I am facing the same issue and have tried many things but problem is still there .. :( Any help would be great.

Comment: I was also able to fix by updating modules. To determine if its modules, remove all modules from tiamm.xml and try building, if it makes it to launching the simulator, then its a module issue and you'll need to work through them one by one to determine what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR: read the bold text.**

I have struggled with this problem for over a day, did a completely clean reinstall of my Mac, Titanium and xCode, and it still gave me this error.

I created a new project, and as soon as I tried to run it (with the Titanium example code still in it). I got the exact same error.

Turns out, for me the problem was that I was trying to create the project on an external (server) hard drive, over an ethernet connection. This seemed to somehow corrupt the tiapp.xml as soon as it was generated, even though on a manual inspection I couldn't find anything.

**The solution for me was to create the project on a local hard drive.** (On the Mac, not on the server.) You can then copy it to a server if you want. This seems to be an issue with Macs not always liking to work with Windows based filesystems.

Hope this helps someone.