# Build Failed Error in Titanium iOS project

Tags: titanium, titanium-modules, titanium-alloy

I am using Titanium 3.1.3 GA version.

While include mobile app tracking module in project, getting "Build Failed" Error message.

Tried with new project also getting the same error.

```
[ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED **

[ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:

[ERROR] :  Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MoibleAppTrackingSample.app/MoibleAppTrackingSample normal i386

[ERROR] :  (1 failure)
```

Please let me know about the issue and how could i fix this.

Comment: Checkout this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973170/titanium-appcelerator-failing-on-build#15975801), it might help you

Answer (score 1):

i386 means you were running on IOS, if yes then please paste the whole log here, so that we can figure it out actually. Because there may be many issue like sdk problem and all. i386 architecture is used for simulators.
Go in finder where this project is and then click `BUILD/iphone/` then click on Xcode project. And from there try to build.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any more details about in the log?

What module did you use? did you download it from the MarketPlace?

Try doing a Clean Project and try again.

Comment: I used mobile app tracking module, purchased from marketplace

Comment: did you do a Project Clean? please provide a link to that module so I will try to compile an app with it included on my machine...

Comment: can you give the module link?